# How to alter imported dataset without it disappearing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have imported a data set from Sheet A to Sheet B in a google sheets workbook using a Query function (=Query(Original_Data!A1:G, "SELECT B, C, -1*D, E, F, G",1).

I am now looking to alter some of the data in the copied data set (Sheet B), but cannot do so without everything disappearing.

I realize this is likely due to how Query works - so I am looking for an alternative solution to copy the data set from sheet A to B (regularly).

I am considering creating a macro that can repeat a simple copy and paste with the click of the button.

I am not sure if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need copy a RANGE, use the formula **IMPORTRANGE**

if you need alter the query, you need to do via query lenguaje

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

query lenguaje is like SQL, if your data is normalize probably you can go in this way

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the best solution. You are, so to speak, wanting to have your cake and to eat it - so bake another.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apps Script, you can use the methods `getValues()` and `setValues()` to copy ONLY the values, so that you can alter the data in both sheets independently. You can run your Apps Script code as a macro. Here some useful links:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues